# Jupyter notebook has become very slow suddenly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I used to run jupyter in an anaconda environment very well.
After showing a warning on

```
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.
```

once I changed it by this command:

```
$jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=2147483647
```

it has suddenly become very slow, even it is not opening the content of the notebook. In the left bottom of Google chrome browser shows :

[image]

And take long time to open the notebook, and the color of the opened notebook in `Home` is not green. I do not know why?
What is the reason and how can I restart Jupyter Notebook configuration?

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 19):

I was having the same problem with the Jupyter notebook. I realized that Jupiter gets too slow when I set the limits too high.

For example,

`import pandas as pd`

`pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 50000)` was causing serious time issues.

I changed it to:

`pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 50)` and the problem was solved.

In your case, you can use:

`$jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000`

I think this will solve your problem.

Thanks

Comment: Solved my problem, had `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)` which was really slowing down the notebook.  Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: What is `pd`? It doesn't appear to be defined in the original question either…

Comment: @EricOLebigot it likely refers to the `pandas` package, often used when working with data.

Comment: Ah, of course, thanks, you're right: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html. I edited the answer to make this explicit.